# How can I modify sample application so that RTMP injection video is first in the UI?

Tags: agora.io

I am using the sample [RTMP Injection](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Interactive-Broadcasting/tree/master/Live-Streaming/Agora-Interactive-Broadcasting-Live-Streaming-Web-Webpack) application for testing purposes. I want to  modify the app in such a way that the injected RTMP stream should be the first video to occur in the grid of remote streams. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the first item of your grid with a similar code from [agora-broadcast-client.js](https://github.com/digitallysavvy/agora-web-broadcast-demo/blob/master/js/agora-broadcast-client.js) in https://github.com/digitallysavvy/agora-web-broadcast-demo using Vanilla JS:

```js
// RTMP Connection (UI Component)
function addExternalTransmitionMiniView(rtmpUrl){
  var container = $('#rtmp-controlers');
  // append the remote stream template to #remote-streams
  container.append(
    $('<div/>', {'id': 'rtmp-container',  'class': 'container row justify-content-end mb-2'}).append(
      $('<div/>', {'class': 'pulse-container'}).append(
          $('<button/>', {'id': 'rtmp-toggle', 'class': 'btn btn-lg col-flex pulse-button pulse-anim mt-2'})
      ),
      $('<input/>', {'id': 'rtmp-url', 'val': rtmpUrl, 'class': 'form-control col-flex" value="rtmps://live.facebook.com', 'type': 'text', 'disabled': true}),
      $('<button/>', {'id': 'removeRtmpUrl', 'class': 'btn btn-lg col-flex close-btn'}).append(
        $('<i/>', {'class': 'fas fa-xs fa-trash'})
      )
    )
  );
}
```

You can hence set where you want the stream to be injected.